# Why did the Sinclair QL keyboard lack a Delete key?

Tags: keyboards, sinclair, sinclair-ql

It seems like an odd key to omit, given how frequently used it is and given that both the Spectrum + and 128 have one, which acts like backspace does on a modern PC. They could have swapped it for two of the lesser-used characters and placed those on alphanumeric keys with a modifier.

Reference picture from Wikipedia:

[image]

Comment: To lazy to write an answer... https://archive.org/details/h42_Sinclair_QL_User_Guide/page/n13/mode/2up  <ctrl>+<leftarrow> were used as rubout/delete They are next to each other, so very easy to use.

Comment: This is one of those questions that only can be answered correctly if someone either was part of the team making the decision or if someone can dig up a document where the decision is discussed.

Comment: @UncleBod, it's not easy to use, it's slower. A DELETE key is easy to use. It's a good question for the site.

Comment: The Title could be improved by asking why it lacks *both* Delete and Backspace keys. My first impression of the original Title was, "why does it matter?", as back then I used only the backspace key (in fact I think we used the DEL key as interrupt (like ^C is commonly used now).

Comment: AFAIK all of previous Sinclair machines (the various ZX models) lacked it, too. They all used a key combination (shift+0 on the ZX80/81 and Spectrum, shift+left for the Spectrum Plus) for "backspace". Cheapness was a paramount quality at Sinclair :)

Comment: @wazoox your memory deceives you; the Spectrum + and 128 onwards do indeed have a Delete key on the left hand side: https://en.wikipedia.org/ZX_Spectrum shows them clearly.

Comment: @user3570736 The QL was released on 12 January 1984, the Spectrum + in October 1984. So all _previous_ ZX machines lacked a delete key.

Comment: Ah apologies for my lack of reading comprehension, I hadn't appreciated that the QL came first so this makes a lot more sense to me now.

Answer (score 8):

As Uncle Bod already [pointed out](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13817/why-did-the-sinclair-ql-keyboard-lack-a-delete-key#comment44002_13817), the QL did not leave out Rubout (as Sinclair called it). It's just not printed on the keycap. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>⇐</kbd>, a combination that seems quite logical to me, will work as expected.

Having it as a shifted function of on another key isn't as unusual as it seems. Already the [ADM-3A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM-3A#ADM-3A) placed RUB as [<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM-3A#/media/File:KB_Terminal_ADM3A.svg)(*1), which in turn took the placement right of `RUB` at the end of the middle (ASDF) row from the [Model 33 TTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletype_Model_33).

---

*1 - The ADM-3A is notorious for having introduced several key assignments - like <kbd>H</kbd>/<kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>L</kbd> for `vi` cursor movement :)

Comment: "RUB OUT" is the proper name, as anyone familiar with an ASR-33 teletype will tell you  :-)

Comment: @another-dave Yeah, 3 layouts, 3 names for the same thing. One got to love it ...

Comment: Is it HJKK or HJKL?

Comment: The K key makes up its own mind whether you meant "up" or "right" ?   ;-)

Comment: @another-dave Oh, drats. As soon as Larry Tesler dies, copy-past-error rate climbs :) Thanks.

Comment: @another-dave: The "rub out" functionality if an ASR-33 is very context sensitive.  It will only rub out a character if the tape has been manually reversed previously.  On the other hand, some details of DC2/DC4 behavior is seem a bit weird.

Comment: The QL actually did call that key combination "Delete" in all Sinclair documents. "Rubout" was a 9 Tiles term (the external company that did the ZX ROMs), while the QL ROMs were developed by Tony Tebby and Jan Jones, at that time Sinclair employees who used "Delete".

Answer (score 5):

The Sinclair QL has not (at least not very much besides the general cost-savy technical design and the Microdrives) been influenced a lot by ZX Spectrum computers - It's rather the other way round: ZX Spectrum Plus and Toastrack did pick up the Dickinson design of the QL computer (For those not familiar with the timeline: The QL was the first Sinclair computer that used that "new", blocky design - Both Spectrum Plus and Spectrum 128 came **after** the QL).

The QL introduced a "Standard line editor" that understands a lot more Cursor key combinations than just "delete" (<CTRL>Right) and "backspace" (<CTRL>Left). There's word-wise (<Shift>+Cursor), line-wise (<ALT>+Cursor) and page-wise (<Shift><ALT>+Cursor) forward and backward movement and deletion (with added <CTRL>) key combos defined in the line editor implemented by QDOS, so it appears somewhat logical that engineers didn't design in an extra key for just one of many operations.

<Cursor>+<CTRL> deletes a character

add <Shift> and it deletes a word

add <ALT> will delete a line and

add both <Shift> and <ALT>  will delete a page.